# Where do you put page-specific scripts in Ionic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am making an app with ionic and I have JS scripts for each page. For example, one page has a script that will change the message based on time of day, while another page has a jQuery .load() script. Neither seems to be working. They are DOM-manipulative, and are at the bottom of the page.

```
<ion-view view-title="Welcome" style="text-align:center; padding:20px;">
  <ion-content>
    <h1 id="time">Hello!</h1>
      <p>Welcome to the app. We are thrilled to share our new app with you!</p>
  </ion-content>
   <script>
       date = new Date();
       var hours = date.getHours();
       console.log(hours);
       if (hours >= 5 && hours <= 11) //MESSAGE FOR MORNING
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = 'Good Morning.';
else if (hours >= 12 && hours <= 17) //MESSAGE FOR AFTERNOON
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = 'Good Afternoon.';
else if (hours >= 18 && hours <= 20) //MESSAGE FOR EVENING (6pm-8pm)
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = 'Good Evening.';
else //MESSAGE FOR NIGHT (9pm-4am)
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = 'Good Night.';</script> 
</ion-view>
```

Controllers.js:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout) {
  // Form data for the login modal
  $scope.loginData = {};

  // Create the login modal that we will use later
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });

  // Triggered in the login modal to close it
  $scope.closeLogin = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };

  // Open the login modal
  $scope.login = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };

  // Perform the login action when the user submits the login form
  $scope.doLogin = function() {
    console.log('Doing login', $scope.loginData);

    // Simulate a login delay. Remove this and replace with your login
    // code if using a login system
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.closeLogin();
    }, 1000);
  };
})

.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.playlists = [
    { title: 'Reggae', id: 1 },
    { title: 'Chill', id: 2 },
    { title: 'Dubstep', id: 3 },
    { title: 'Indie', id: 4 },
    { title: 'Rap', id: 5 },
    { title: 'Cowbell', id: 6 }
  ];
})

.controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
});
```

Comment: I think this logic should actually go in either a controller or a service. Not in the template for that view.

Comment: What do you mean? @w1zeman1p

Comment: If you're starting from one of the ionic starter apps you should have a controllers.js file that might have a WelcomeCtrl. in that controller function i would probably attach the message as part of the scope. Could you post the controllers.js file? Or any of your controllers? I'll try to help from there. :)

Comment: Great. Som each of these controllers is the code backing each "page" as it stands it looks like you've got a welcome page that needs a controller and very likely you'll need to update the routes in app.js

Comment: How do you do this? @w1zeman1p

Comment: Can you add app.js? What's the name of the html file above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the scripts in the `controller.js` file. You add the following code:

```
.controller('PageCtrl', function($scope){
//Insert function code here
})
```

On the ionic page, in the `<ion-view>` parameters, you set `"ng-controller"` to `PageCtrl`. Inside your DOM-manipulating div, you put something like `<div>{{hello}}</div>`. Then you finish it all off by using `$scope.hello = "Your String";` inside of your controller to manipulate the DOM elements.